complete beginner, need help with figures
i am a complete beginner. i don't know  much about latex. i need help with positioning images. basically, there's 6 figures and i want them to be subfigures, where two each are side by side. i am dropping my code below.
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t][0.49\textwidth]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{pt 900/p900.png}
    \caption{$p_T$ spectra of p at 900}
    \label{fig:1-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t][0.49\textwidth]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{pt 900/pbar900.png}
    \caption{$p_T$ spectra of pbar at 900 GeV}
    \label{fig:1-b}
\end{subfigure}


\caption{$p_T$ spectra of identified charged particles at 900 GeV}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

i have repeated the subfigure thing 6 times.  the problem is i first of all am not getting the desired reult. secondly, i am getting these two errors for every subfigure.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.34         \centering
                       
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)



<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.34         \centering
                       
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

please please someone help me. i have tried everything but cant seem to figure it out. i urgently need this.
PS: my preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}


You're probably mixing the notation/syntax from other sub-float related packages. When using subcaption, it provides a subfigure environment which is similar to the subcaptionblock environment and takes a single, mandatory argument. You currently supply vertical position and width arguments as optional, which is the cause of the issue.
Use the following instead:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{$p_T$ spectra of p at 900}
    \label{fig:1-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{$p_T$ spectra of pbar at 900 GeV}
    \label{fig:1-b}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{$p_T$ spectra of identified charged particles at 900 GeV}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Note the following:

Single, mandatory argument for subfigure that defines the width of the box that subfigure will be placed in (internally it will use subcaptionblock).

With the width of the block set (to 0.49\textwidth, say), you can just use width=\linewidth for the \includegraphics scaling and it will fill the entire width of the block.

It seems like you just want a space between the two subfigures, so no \centering needed, only \hfill.



thank you so much! that was a grreat help, seriously!!
